# Is Cassandra's hash for same value across multiple tables?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a multi-tenant application where tenantId would be part of every query, so I am putting it into the partition key for all tables.

EXAMPLES:

```
CREATE TABLE users {
tenantId text,
user text,
active boolean,
PRIMARY_KEY (tenantId, user)
}

CREATE TABLE roles {
tenantId text,
rolename text,
PRIMARY_KEY (tenantId, rolename)
}
```

**Now, imagine 100s of tables like these...**

**My question is:**

Will Cassandra hash the tenantId 'foo' to point ALL data from ALL tables to the same node and make it a *uber* hotspot or will it evenly distribute each table & tenant data around the cluster evenly?

Comment: The token is a hash of the primary key so putting tenantId in every partition key won't help. I wonder how many unique tenantIds you will generate? In some cases with low cardinality, secondary indexes might make sense.  Richard Low [explains it](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=77) much better than I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer, the token value (hash of the partition key) is the same and it does not depend on the table name or whatever. The reason is that we use the same partition (**Murmur3**) within the whole cluster.

So in your case, yes, if your partition key is *tenantId*, all data from one customer will be distributed to the same replicas, and this applies for **all tables** having this partition key

Comment: So, I'd have to create a dummy partition key bucket for each like this then, to spread them around:  Partition key for "users" PRIMARY_KEY ( (tenantId, tablename), user) where tablename is always "users" and for "roles" PRIMARY_KEY ( (tenantId, tablename), rolename) where tablename is always "roles".  What do you think?

Comment: It won't solve the fundamental issue of poor distribution with regard to tenandID. Even if you add table name as extra partition key component, the total number of partitions used for 1 tenant = number of tables. I doubt you have 1000 tables so ultimately, the data for 1 tenant will be distributed to a few partitions only, as many partitions as there are distinct tables

Comment: Can you provide an example of how Achilles generated tables would look like in a multi-tenant design?  I looked and could not find a multi-tenant doc page, but I know you had support for multi-tenancy at some point.

Comment: Multi tenancy in Achilles rely on dynamic table lookup at runtime. At runtime, you can do a `select().xxx().fromTable(schemaProvider).where().tenantId_Eq(...)`. All the table lookup is done by the schemaProvider. In this case, multi tenancy is achieved by having different table/keyspace for different customers/group of customers